# autoconf stopped with "error: m4_defn: undefined macro: _m4_divert_diversion"

Tags: mpi, autoconf, automake, m4

I am building OpenMPI-1.6.5. After I run autogen.sh, I have got following error:

```
...
patching file opal/libltdl/loaders/preopen.c
   ++ patching for ifort (LT 2.2.0-4)
     -- your libltdl doesn't need this! yay!
[Running] aclocal -I config -I opal/config -I orte/config -I ompi/config
configure.ac:35: error: m4_defn: undefined macro: _m4_divert_diversion
configure.ac:35: the top level
autom4te: /usr/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 1
aclocal: autom4te failed with exit status: 1
```

What can be the problem?

I have tools: automake 1.10.1, autoconf 2.63, m4 1.4.12

Any help will be appreciated.

Best,
   Alex

Comment: Why would you run autogen.sh just to build a package?  Unless you are maintaining openMPI and building the tarballs, you have no need to run the autotools.  Download the tarball and run the configure script.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did know that autogen.sh is not needed for regular built.